# Phone number storage in Core Data

Tags: ios, core-data, ios5

What's the best practice? NSString or NSNumber?

P.S. I will that user can dial a number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A NSString, you can check the validity of the phone number with NSDataDetector APIs